# Can we determine the determinant?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Could someone prove that this determinant is not zero?
$$\left|
      \begin{array}{cccc}
        1^n & 2^n & \cdots & (n+1)^n \\
        2^n & 3^n & \cdots & (n+2)^n \\
        \vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots \\
        (n+1)^n & (n+2)^n & \cdots & (2n+1)^n \\
      \end{array}
    \right|\neq0$$
How can we compute it?

Answer (score 0):

These determinants are equal to $(-1)^{\textrm{Floor}((n+1)/2)}(n!)^{n+1}$

For the proof see:

J. M. Monier, Algebre & geometrie, Dunod (1996), p.216.

Added: I cannot find the original proof (I used to have the original edtion but the only printings I can find are the 5th edition where he's taken this proof out--apparently) but I do have a heuristic method:

Let $R = \left(\begin{array}{cccc}1^n & 2^n &\cdots & (n+1)^n\\2^n & 3^n & \cdots & (n+2)^n\\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ (n+1)^n & (n+2)^n & \cdots & (2n+1)^n\end{array}\right)$

If we row operate by subtracting the previous row from each row beginning with row 2.

i.e. $\tilde{R}_{i,j} \gets R_{i,j} - R_{i-1,j}$

Then repeat this same but starting this time with row 3. And continue repeating--each time beginning one row further down you will wind up with:

$$\tilde{R}_k =R_k + (-1)^1{k-1 \choose 1}R_{k-1} + (-1)^2{k -1\choose 2}R_{k-2} +\cdots+(-1)^{k-1}{k -1\choose k-1}R_{1}$$ 
where$R_j$ is an original row vector of $R$. Part of the magic of the proof is that this operation will transform the final row to be a constant value of $n!$. 
This is because
$$(k+n)^n - {n \choose 1}(k+n-1)^n + {n\choose 2}(k+n-2)^n +\cdots+(-1)^n{n\choose n}k^n = n!$$for each $k$.

Since the original matrix is symmetric, you can do the same operation on the columns and get a similar result. In fact if you do this operation on the rows, then the columns you'll get A matrix with $n!$ down the anti-diagonal and zeros below the anti-diagonal. The values above the anti-diagonal appear to be OEIS: A142071 although I have no idea why. The important thing for the determinant is that you can rearrange the rows to get an upper diagonal matrix with $n!$ on the diagonal. This rearranging gives  $\det R =(-1)^{\textrm{Floor}((n+1)/2)}(n!)^{n+1}$.

Comment: I didn't find the material in this book, could you give me some hints? By the way, let $f(x)$ be a polynomial of degree $n-1$ over a characteristic zero field and let $k_1,\dots,k_n$ be different numbers, could we prove that $f(x+k_1),\dots,f(x+k_n)$ is a basis of the vector space of polynomials of degree less or equal than $n-1$. I want to use difference of these polynomials to construct a sequence of polynomials of degree $0,1,\dots,n-1$, but i face some difficulty.

Comment: Not sure. Um OK I will try to locate the full proof for you. As I recall it relies on the strange fact that $\det((n+1)R S) = \det Q$ where $S_{ij} = i^{-j}$ and $Q$ is a Vandemonde matrix.

Comment: I have proved the claim that $f(x+k_1),\dots,f(x+k_n)$ is a basis. But still can't able to compute this determinant.

Comment: The following is my proof: Without loss of generality, we assume that
$$f(x)=x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+a_{n-2}x^{n-2}+\cdots+a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0.$$
 Then  \begin{eqnarray*}

    f(x+k_i) &=& (x+k_i)^n+a_{n-1}(x+k_i)^{n-1}+a_{n-2}(x+k_i)^{n-2}+\cdots+a_2(x+k_i)^2+a_1(x+k_i)+a_0 \\
&=& x^n+(C^1_n k_i+a_{n-1})x^{n-1}+(C^2_nk_i^2+a_{n-1}C^1_{n-1}k_i+a_{n-1})x^{n-2}+\cdots \\
&+& (C^{n-1}_nk_i^{n-1}+a_{n-1}C^{n-2}_{n-1}k^{n-2}_i+\cdots+a_2C^1_2k_i+a_1)x+C^n_nk^n_i+a_{n-1}C^{n-1}_{n-1}k^{n-1}_i+\cdots+a_2C^2_2k^2_i+a_1C^1_1k_i+a_0
  \end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Let $p_0(x)=1,p_1(x)=C^1_n x+a_{n-1},p_2(x)=C^2_nx^2+a_{n-1}C^1_{n-1}x+a_{n-1},
  p_{n-1}(x)=C^{n-1}_nx^{n-1}+a_{n-1}C^{n-2}_{n-1}x^{n-2}+\cdots+a_2C^1_2x+a_1$ and
  $p_n(x)=C^n_nx^n+a_{n-1}C^{n-1}_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_2C^2_2x^2+a_1C^1_1x+a_0$. Then we have

Comment: \begin{equation*}
 \left(
 \begin{array}{c}
 f(x+k_1) \\
 f(x+k_2) \\
 \vdots \\
 f(x+k_{n+1}) \\
 \end{array}
\right)=\left(
 \begin{array}{cccc}
p_0(k_1) & p_1(k_1) & \cdots & p_n(k_1) \\
p_0(k_2) & p_1(k_2) & \cdots & p_n(k_2) \\
   \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
           p_0(k_{n+1}) & p_{1}(k_{n+1}) & \cdots & p_{n}(k_{n+1}) \\
         \end{array}
       \right)\left(
                \begin{array}{c}
                  x^n \\
                  x^{n-1} \\
                  \vdots \\
                  1 \\
                \end{array}
              \right).
    \end{equation*}

Comment: Since $$\left|
 \begin{array}{cccc}
  p_0(k_1) & p_1(k_1) & \cdots & p_n(k_1) \\
         p_0(k_2) & p_1(k_2) & \cdots & p_n(k_2) \\
           \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
           p_0(k_{n+1}) & p_{1}(k_{n+1}) & \cdots & p_{n}(k_{n+1}) \\
         \end{array}
       \right|=C^0_nC^1_nC^2_n\cdots C^{n-1}_nC^n_n\prod_{1\leq i<j\leq n+1}(k_j-k_i)\neq0.$$
Thus $$\{f(x+k_1),f(x+k_2),\dots,f(x+k_n),f(x+k_{n+1})\}\quad\text{is a basis of $k^{\leq n}[x]$}.$$ $k^{\leq n}[x]$ the the vector space of polynomials of degree less or equal to $n$. Remember the field $k$ is characteristic zero.

Comment: By the way, in your answer, what is $R$. Can we chat by email?

Comment: I have proved this results. Thank you

Comment: Sorry @HGF. I've been AFK during the weekend I usually don't do any math (unfortunately). From your final comment, it looks like you've gotten what you wanted. (I think). My $R$ marix above was just the original matrix you wanted the determinant of. I can clarify if you'd like.

Comment: Yes, of course. Could you explain your method explicitly? Looking forward to hearing from you soon.

Answer (score 0):

First we apply binomial theorem, e.g. write $2^n$ as $(1+1)^n$, then $2^n=1^n+C_n ^1 1^{n-1}1^1+ \cdots+C_n ^n 1^0 1^n$. And note that $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$ for square matrix $A,B$ with same order.
$$\left|
      \begin{array}{cccc}
        1^n & 2^n & \cdots & (n+1)^n \\
        2^n & 3^n & \cdots & (n+2)^n \\
        \vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots \\
        (n+1)^n & (n+2)^n & \cdots & (2n+1)^n \\
      \end{array}
    \right|
=
\left|
      \begin{array}{cccc}
        (0+1)^n & (0+2)^n & \cdots & (0+(n+1))^n \\
        (1+1)^n & (1+2)^n & \cdots & (1+(n+1))^n \\
        \vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots \\
        (n+1)^n & (n+2)^n & \cdots & (n+(n+1))^n \\
      \end{array}
    \right|
=
\left|
      \begin{array}{cccc}
        0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 \\
        1^n & 1^{n-1} & \cdots & 1^0 \\
        \vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots \\
        n^n & n^{n-1} & \cdots & n^0 \\
      \end{array}
    \right| \cdot 
\left|
      \begin{array}{cccc}
        1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\
        C_n^1 1^1 & C_n^1 2^{1} & \cdots & C_n ^1 (n+1)^1 \\
        \vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots \\
        C_n^n 1^n & C_n^n 2^{n} & \cdots & C_n^n (n+1)^n \\
      \end{array}
    \right|
$$
Notice that this 2 matrix are nearly of the Vandermonde form. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix). Except that the first one should have all its columns reversed; the second one should extract the factors $C_n ^1, \dots,C_n ^n$. Hence,
$$
\left|
      \begin{array}{cccc}
        0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 \\
        1^n & 1^{n-1} & \cdots & 1^0 \\
        \vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots \\
        n^n & n^{n-1} & \cdots & n^0 \\
      \end{array}
    \right| \cdot 
\left|
      \begin{array}{cccc}
        1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\
        C_n^1 1^1 & C_n^1 2^{1} & \cdots & C_n ^1 (n+1)^1 \\
        \vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots \\
        C_n^n 1^n & C_n^n 2^{n} & \cdots & C_n^n (n+1)^n \\
      \end{array}
    \right|= \\
(-1)^{n(n+1)/2}C_n ^1 C_n ^2 \cdots C_n ^n 
\left|
      \begin{array}{cccc}
        1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
        1 & 1^{1} & \cdots & 1^n \\
        \vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots \\
        1 & n^{1} & \cdots & n^n \\
      \end{array}
    \right| \cdot 
\left|
      \begin{array}{cccc}
        1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\
         1^1 &  2^{1} & \cdots &   (n+1)^1 \\
        \vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots \\
         1^n &  2^{n} & \cdots &  (n+1)^n \\
      \end{array}
    \right|
\\ =(-1)^{n(n+1)/2}C_n ^1 C_n ^2 \cdots C_n ^n \prod_{0 \leq i <j \leq n}(j-i) \prod_{1 \leq i <j \leq n+1}(j-i)
\neq 0.
$$